# Cancellation Token in Func

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this piece of code

```
public Task<TValue> LoadAsync(TKey key, Func<Task<TValue>> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Doing Stuf
  func();
}
```

Then I have some other piece of code that calls that inherits from that class and class that load async, for instance

```
public void LoadCategories(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  return base.LoadAsync(
    (key, value),
    () => {
      return this.mediator.ExecuteAsync(query, cancellationToken);
    },
    cancellationToken
  );
}
```

My questions is should the func also receive a cancellation token for instance be like this?

```
public Task<TValue> LoadAsync(TKey key, Func<CancellationToken, Task<TValue>> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{  
  // Doing Stuf
  func(cancellationToken);
}
```

And the other should be like this and use the given token instead of use the already present cancellation token?

```
public void LoadCategories(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  base.LoadAsync(
   (key, value),
   (token) => {
     return this.mediator.ExecuteAsync(query, token);
   },
   cancellationToken
  );
}
```

What's the difference of one way or the other if there's a difference.

Comment: Please indent the code snippets.

Comment: @JCarlosR is this better?

Comment: "Should" is not something we can answer. It's up to you and your use cases. Are all of the functions you're looking to pass to `LoadAsync` capable of taking a `CancellationToken`? What does `LoadAsync` itself do with the `CancellationToken` it receives? Seems like the token shouldn't be passed to another function if it's being used by the current function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey From my understanding and from what I was able to read on the [Recommend Pattern for CancellationToken](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/), it's recommended to propagate the CancellationToken, so in my mind i believe that the **Func** that **LoadAsync** takes as parameter should also have a **CancellationToken** and that it should propagate it to the following methods invoqued inside the **LoadAsync**.
I changed the question hopefully it will be easier to understand my doubt of correct usage of the CancellationToken.